# Clear a modification applied for each Button before a switch case access

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have many buttons in my universal app so I end up with code that look like this:

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    choix_buttons(sender, e);
}

private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

   choix_buttons(sender, e);
}
        .........

private async void choix_buttons(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    Button Btn = sender as Button;

    switch (Btn.Name)
    {
            case "btn1":
                //do something for button1's style

                break;

             case "btn2":
                //do something for button2's style

                break;

    }

    ...all the other buttons
}
```

My code applies a specific Style for every selected button, but I have a problem, when I click on button2 it applies the Style for Button2, than when I click on Button1 it applies the style for Button1, and so on, so I get more than a button which has his style applied.

So how can I please clear the modification that I have apply for each Button before access to the switch case clause?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Are all the buttons the same style, before you apply your special style?

Comment: yes Sir,they have the same style before the apply of the special style :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.
1. You can loop through all of your controls, and if it is a button, apply default style. This is problematic if you have buttons you don't want to apply it to.
2. You can hold a reference to the button that is styled, like so:

```
 //Your reference to the styledButton
 private Button styledButton;

 private  void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      choix_buttons(sender, e);
 }
 private  void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
      choix_buttons(sender, e);
 }

 private async void choix_buttons(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

     //Here you can set styledButton = default styling

     Button Btn = sender as Button;

     switch (Btn.Name)
     {
          case "btn1":
              //do something for button1's style
              break;

          case "btn2":
              //do something for button2's style
              break;
     }
              ...all the other buttons

      //And here you set the styledButton = the button that was pressed
      styledButton = Btn;

 }
```

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,so I should loop on my buttons,if a Button is already selected I will assign it the referenced button style

Comment: @user3821206 Yes, that would be a fine way to do it.